# What is returned from msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");?

Tags: address.call

I am working through some sample contracts online and ran across the lines below:

```
(bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
```

require(sent, "Failed to send ETH.");

I understand `.call{}()` and why/how it's used, but haven't been able to find anything explaining the `(bool sent, ) =` portion.

Q1: Does this line instantiate a boolean named "sent" that is then assigned true or false depending on the success of `.call{}()`?

Q2: Does this assignment always need to be coded or can we simply write `address.call{}();`?

Q3: What is going on with the syntax of `(bool sent, )`? Why is there an empty space? Why is it in brackets?

Any and all information would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low level Solidity method `call` performs a call to a contract and returns if this call was successful and the data it returns.

So the full assignment would be:

```js
(bool success, bytes memory data) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
```

As you mentioned this will instantiate the `success` and `data` variables.

Checking `success` (or in your example `sent`) with a require, will enforce that the ETH transfer was successful. If you don't check this it might be possible that the transfer (or call) was not performed.

Here some info why to transfer ETH like this: https://consensys.net/diligence/blog/2019/09/stop-using-soliditys-transfer-now/

Comment: Thank you! I'll read through the blog you linked asap.