# What is the "bytes memory" in (bool success, bytes memory) = some_address.call{value: some_amount}("")

Tags: address.transfer, memory, calldata, callcode, send

I understand that the `success` tells if the receive/fallback methods returned successfully but what does the `memory` give?

Answer (score 1):

The `call` method can be used to send arbitrary data to another contract. If no data is sent this normally triggers the fallback data, but it is also possible to trigger any other function of the target contract. When a function returns data or reverts with an error message then this data will be returned in the `bytes memory`

See https://solidity-by-example.org/call/

Comment: Related to this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118859/what-is-returned-from-msg-sender-callvalue-amount/118861#118861

Comment: Ok so memory might hold an error message like if require(some_condition, "some error message") was triggered. We might see memory = "some error message")? That makes sense. Would you happen to have any links on how to convert `bytes memory` to the return value of a function?